# What is the purpose of the holdout set in k-means clustering?

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means

[Link to the MIT problem set](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-3/lecture-22-using-graphs-to-model-problems-part-2/MIT6_00SCS11_ps10.pdf)

**Here are my current thoughts--please point to where I'm wrong :)**

What I believe: *The holdout set's purpose is to foil,
contrast, for the training set - to prove that the
k-means eliminates error at each round.*

To do this, the holdout set shows the error at the very begin-
ning, i.e. it doesn't recompute the centroid of each clusters
to be at the very center of each cluster, after each
point has been assigned. It just stops, and the error is
calculated.

The training set, for the initial 80% of the points--
partitioned using randomPartition()--simply go through
the entire k-means function, and return the error after
that.)

Where I'm probably wrong: *The problem probably just
requests another run of k-means, but with a smaller set.
Also, the way of calculating error for training set vs. the holdout
set seem identical to me. They're probably not. 
Also, I heard something about it involving feature selection.*

Current methods I'm considering based on current belief:
Duplicate the k-means function, and modify the duplicate
so that it returns the clusters, maxDistance after initial
run. Use this function for the holdout set.

Comment: It's not common to use a holdout set for clustering. Clustering is not classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of clustering is to group similar data points. But how would you know if the similar data points you have grouped are grouped correctly? How can you judge your results? For this reason you divide your available data into 2 sets: training and holdout.

Take this as an analogy.

Think about training set as practice questions for some examination. You work the practice questions, try to do best in it and improve your skills.

You can think holdout set as the actual examination. If you have worked good on the practice questions (training set) then you will probably perform good in the examination (holdout set).

Now you know how well did you do in practice and examination (of-course after attempting ) based on which you can infer your overall performance and judge what is good (what number of clusters are good or how good is the data clustered).

So you will apply your clustering algorithm on the training data but not on holdout data and find out cluster centers (representatives of clusters). For holdout data, you will simply use the cluster centers you have found from algorithm and assign data-points to cluster whose center is nearest. Calculate your performance on training and holdout data based on some performance metric (squared distance error in your case). Finally compare these metrics over different values of k to get a good judgement. There is more to it but for assignment sake it seems enough.

In practice, there are many other methods. But the key idea in most of them is same. There is a statistics community where you can find more similar questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#Holdout_method